# My app getting crashed when i restart my Mobile

Tags: java, android

Am developing an GPS tracking Application. It's getting crashed when we restart mobile phone. And also please help me to make app compatible with all android devices.
This is My Manifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gpstracking"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
     >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="19"
        />        
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" android:exported="true"/>   

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@id/btnShowLocation"
        android:allowBackup="true" android:theme="@style/gps">
        <activity
            android:name=".AndroidGPSTrackingActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: It's not necessary to support devices that run android version smaller than SDK 9/10. See [this](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=ausdroid.net)

Comment: GPS is not switching on correctly whats the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
  <compatible-screens>
<!-- all small size screens -->
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />


<!-- support for Xperia Z, Galaxy S4 and HTC One -->
<screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="normal" /> 
<screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="large" /> 
</compatible-screens>
```

Try this code in the manifest I think this will work.. Other wise Create separate folders in res folder like layout-small, layout-large, layout-normal, and use appropriate images in the drawable folder drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi... I am sure this will help you for various screen orientation..

for GPS issue [use this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/)